# Ways to differentiate between multiple Kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

So we maintain a number of Kubernetes dashboards for different environments, and they're kept as similar as possible so our environments stay relatively consistent. Is there any way to modify the dashboard to make it clear exactly which Kubernetes cluster I'm currently connected to without needing to look back at which gcloud credentials are currently activated?

Comment: I'm not aware of a dashboard feature that would do that but via the CLI `kubectl config get-contexts` gives you a list of all contexts (environments) with the current, active one highlighted with a `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the system-banner dashboard argument:

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Dashboard-arguments

Comment: Oh that's really cool actually; how do I set that up in the GKE context though? I haven't seen any obvious way to configure that yet.

Comment: Update: Tried to do this by adding an `args` option to the kubernetes-dashboard deployment container configuration and made my dashboard totally inaccessible. Oops. Rolled it back and updated the cluster to fix the tls certificate errors that caused and learned a valuable lesson in not modifying the thing I use to modify things.